# Why I can't render items of an array in table data in react

Tags: reactjs

This is the column part which i have declared.

```
{
            title: 'Tags',
            key: 'tags',
            dataIndex: 'tags',
            render: (_,{tags})=>{
                <>
                    {tags.map((tag)=>{
                        return(
                            <Tag key={tag}>{tag}</Tag>
                        );
                    })}
                </>
            }
}
```

I have tried the code too that is given in antd official site. why this way doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `return` statement

```
{
            title: 'Tags',
            key: 'tags',
            dataIndex: 'tags',
            render: (_,{tags})=>{
               return <>
                    {tags.map((tag)=>{
                        return(
                            <Tag key={tag}>{tag}</Tag>
                        );
                    })}
                </>
            }
}
```